# Pan map with mouse wheel click instead of left click

Tags: cesiumjs, resium

The default behavior of panning the map is via left click + drag I would like to change that behavior to be with wheel click + drag.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's handled by the `ScreenSpaceCameraController`, and is configurable.  For [example](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=nVHLTsMwEPyVVU6thGwBx6YVqKkQUhESRZwsITfZUAvbG9mbVOXrcRoeBXopBz9mZ2bHj5J8ZOgMbjHAFDxuYY7RtE487WsjlZV7PCfP2ngMKhtPlFdeSqgpwGUBjipUfughYoke0xwQ/arRJc61w6B7eyBrkyIQa8ZFh54fdw3GFPsROUi/GHF3WxTLxXPxcH1zGHlxciQH7aP9f2pARx3CAQN1IAe8QWBqgOphayx/J4hTDvjTGTem5lH/ztlZprK0AnwOgDzyzuJsAABXxjUUGNpgR0JIRtf0V41y3ZavyKKMcTz5cMpDa16ZDkw1PfLFUFodY2Lq1tqVeUOVzXKZ9H+slnRl/Mt9h8HqXS/bnM+WQ1EIkcsEjzuZyK51+NX5HQ):

```js
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

// for 3D mode
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.rotateEventTypes = Cesium.CameraEventType.MIDDLE_DRAG;

// for 2D mode
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.translateEventTypes = Cesium.CameraEventType.MIDDLE_DRAG;

// remove MIDDLE_DRAG from the top of the tiltEventTypes.
viewer.scene.screenSpaceCameraController.tiltEventTypes.shift();
```

That last command above uses `Array.shift` to remove the first element of the `tiltEventTypes` array.  The default value of this array (for many versions of Cesium) is [shown here](https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/blob/20c305e94d80a76ff750cfc2fea17d22cb7e5b58/packages/engine/Source/Scene/ScreenSpaceCameraController.js#L193):

```js
this.tiltEventTypes = [
    CameraEventType.MIDDLE_DRAG,
    CameraEventType.PINCH,
    {
      eventType: CameraEventType.LEFT_DRAG,
      modifier: KeyboardEventModifier.CTRL,
    },
    {
      eventType: CameraEventType.RIGHT_DRAG,
      modifier: KeyboardEventModifier.CTRL,
    },
  ];
```

This is showing us that one can still issue "tilt" events even after shifting away the `MIDDLE_DRAG` entry.  We can CTRL-left-drag, for example, to get the same action.